# Translating model attributes for devise error messages breaks form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-i18n

I have ajax devise forms that on error append field and message of error to the bottom of the form.

On ajax:error I do following:

```
$.each(errors, function(field, messages){
  error_div.append(field + " " + "messages)
});
```

I want to translate the errors that are sent and for messages that devise generate I've found an answer on SO that works for me (adding it in my translation file):

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      accepted: "have to be checked"
```

Now when I get an error it is like following:

> terms_and_conditions have to be checked

So next on my list was somehow translating these modal attributes

So I found another SO post that explained a way to translate model attributes like following:

```
activerecord:
  models:
    recruiter:
      terms_and_conditions: "Terms and conditions"
```

But I got a 501 server error,
After tracing the bug and printing the error it is as following:

````
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData at /recruiters
=============================================

> translation data {:terms_and_conditions=>"TERMS TRANSLATION"} can not be used with :count => 1

app/controllers/recruiters/registrations_controller.rb, line 8
``` ruby
    3   
    4     def create
    5       respond_to do |format|
    6         format.json {
    7           build_resource(sign_up_params)
>   8           if resource.save
    9             RegistrationMailer.recruiter(resource.id).deliver_later! if Rails.env.production?
   10             sign_in(resource_name, resource)
   11             if ['true', true].include?(params[:get_token])
   12               token = resource.generate_authentication_token!
   13               render json: { id: resource.id, email: resource.email, authentication_token: token }
````

So I looked for the error InvalidPluralizationData and found an answer that explained you need both singular and plural translations.
So I changed I tried

```
activerecord:
  models:
    recruiter:
      terms_and_conditions:
        one: "Term and condition singular test"
        other: "Term and conditions plural test"
```

But the same error still applies with different params:

## I18n::InvalidPluralizationData at /recruiters

```
translation data {:company_name=>{:one=>"Term and condition singular test", :other=>"Term and conditions plural test"}} can not be used with :count => 1
```

I havent been able to find a suitable solution to also translate these model attributes without breaking the whole form (i'm not able to submit the form even if I try to translate the attributes).

Any help is greatly appreciated.